# OpenGL Threaded Render with QGLContext

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, opengl, qglwidget

I want to render image with OpenGL from separate thread in Qt 5.2 according to Qt [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qglwidget.html#details) Threading section.
The following code

```
QGLWidget *widget = new QGLWidget();
widget->doneCurrent();
QThread *thread = new QThread();
widget->context()->moveToThread(thread);
```

produce assert *"Cannot make QOpenGLContext current in a different thread"* which does not correlate to what documentation says. 
Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You should create your `QGLWidget` __inside__ the new thread.

Comment: QWidget can not be created outside GUI thread

Comment: Oh, my! Also, by "render" do you mean "call qt-opengl api functions" or "calculate the info/data of elements to be drawn"? If the latest, you should do a separate class (sa `class ProcessElements`) that communicates when such data is ready. The [mandelbrot qt example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcore-threads-mandelbrot-example.html) does this.